# Deduplicate dataframe based on criteria in R?

Tags: r, sorting, duplicates

I've got this dataframe:

```
    Name    Country Gender  Age
1   John      GB      M     25
2   Mark      US      M     35
3   Jane      0       0      0
4   Jane      US      F     30
5   Jane      US      F      0
6   Kate      GB      F     18
```

As you can see the value "Jane" appears 3 times. What I want to do is to deduplicate the list based on the variable "Name" but because the rest of the columns are important to me, I want to keep the rows that have the most information in them. For example if I was to deduplicate the above file in excel, it would keep the first value of "Jane" and delete all the other ones. But the first value of "Jane" (row no3) has got missing information in the other columns.

So in other words I want to deduplicate the list by "Name" but add a criteria to keep the rows that have any other value different from "0" in the column "Age". This way the result I would get would be this:

```
    Name    Country Gender  Age
1   John       GB     M     25
2   Mark       US     M     35
3   Jane       US     F     30
4   Kate       GB     F     18
```

I have tried this

```
file3 <- file1[!duplicated(file1$Name),]
```

But like excel it keeps the value of "Jane" that has no usable information in the other columns.

How do I sort the rows based on column "Age" in a Z-A order so that anything that has "0" will be on the bottom and will be removed when I deduplicate the list?

Cheers

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this trick

```
ind <- with(DF, 
        Country !=0 &
        Gender %in% c('F', 'M') &
        Age !=0)

DF[ind, ]
  Name Country Gender Age
1 John      GB      M  25
2 Mark      US      M  35
4 Jane      US      F  30
6 Kate      GB      F  18
```

So far it works well and produces your desired output

**EDIT**

```
 library(doBy)
    orderBy(~ -Age+Name, DF) # Sort decreasingly by Age and Name

  Name Country Gender Age
2 Mark      US      M  35
4 Jane      US      F  30
1 John      GB      M  25
6 Kate      GB      F  18
3 Jane       0      0   0
5 Jane      US      F   0
```

Or simply using Base functions:

```
DF[order(DF$Age, DF$Name, decreasing = TRUE), ]
  Name Country Gender Age
2 Mark      US      M  35
4 Jane      US      F  30
1 John      GB      M  25
6 Kate      GB      F  18
3 Jane       0      0   0
5 Jane      US      F   0
```

Now you can select by indexing the correct rows meeting your conditions, I really think the first part is better than these two lasts.

Comment: That looks like a complicated formula and I can't seem to understand exactly how it works and what it does. Is there no simpler way to just sort the rows in the dataframe by the column "Age" in Z-A order?

Comment: The reason why I need something simpler is because my dataframes have got thousahds of unique values in the"name" columns and have got about 70-80 columns in total, each with at least 50 unique values in them. By the looks of your formula I would have to write those values everytime I want to do this operation. David

Comment: @DavidRogers see my edit where I ordered the data.frame decreasingly by Age and NAme as you wanted.

Comment: Does this mean I have to download a package called "doBy"? It gives me this error Error: could not find function "orderby. Error in library(doBy) : there is no package called ‘doBy    Thanks

Comment: Jilber, the last one in your list works just perfect for me. Thanks so much. David

Comment: Yes, if you want to use `orderBy` you have to install doBy package (by doing `install.packages("doBy")`). Glad to be useful, you can also upvote the answer.

Comment: Jilber, one more question, is it possible to sort by column index, not by column name?

Comment: Yes it is!. try `DF[order(DF[,4], DF[,1], decreasing = TRUE), ]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. All the best. David

Answer (score 1):

If all duplicated rows have the value zero in column `Age`, it will work with `subset`:

```
# the data
file1 <- read.table(text="Name    Country Gender  Age
1   John      GB      M     25
2   Mark      US      M     35
3   Jane      0       0      0
4   Jane      US      F     30
5   Jane      US      F      0
6   Kate      GB      F     18", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# create a subset of the data
subset(file1, Age > 0)

#   Name Country Gender Age
# 1 John      GB      M  25
# 2 Mark      US      M  35
# 4 Jane      US      F  30
# 6 Kate      GB      F  18
```

Comment: This is usefull to have handy. Thanks Sven